# Verneinter Aussage wurde »Wirklich?« entgegnet – wie antworte ich?

Tags: word-choice, negation

Ich hatte gerade ein Gespräch, das ungefähr wie folgt ablief:

> Ich: »Gerade war auf der Straße wirklich noch nichts los!«
>
> Gesprächspartner: »Wirklich?«

Und ich habe mich gefragt, was die richtige Antwort wäre (davon ausgehend, dass ich am Anfang Recht hatte):

- > Nein [da war wirklich nichts los].
- > Ja [das, was ich gerade gesagt habe, stimmte].

Was ist das Richtige, wenn man nur kurz seine vorherige Antwort bestätigen will?

Comment: "Wirklich?" is just another way to say "Ist das wahr?" and I guess the appropriate answer to that question is more obvious, isn't it?

Comment: In such cases a simple "Ja" may be a bit lame. There are  a lot of possibilities to give your answer more weight, for instance: Wenn ich dirs sage. Es war nichts los/Es war kein Rattenschwanz zu sehen.

Comment: Ich glaube, die Grammatik im Titel ist daneben: Dir wurde auf die die Aussage etwas entgegnet.

Answer (score 5):

Ich würde sagen: "Ja!"
Denn der Gesprächspartner hat - rein formal gesehen - Deine Aussage in Zweifel gezogen und mit "Ja!" bekräftigst Du Deine Aussage.
Real wird man wohl sagen: "Ja, wirklich!" oder ähnliches, um die Ambiguität aufzuheben.

Anders formuliert (direkter):

> Ich: "Es war nichts los."
>   Er: "Ist das wahr?"
>   Ich "Ja."

Comment: Oder "ja, wirklich!"

Answer (score 2):

A bit tricky – but probably less tricky, than it first seems. I do understand the first option "*Nein*" and every now and then I'm tempted to use it myself – although that would probably be considered a bit confusing. As far as I understand the usage of "*Wirklich?*" correctly, it is related to your statement – and not what you are actually saying. So "*Ja*" would then underline the correctness of your original statement.

I would consider the question "*Wirklich?*" as a short for "*Ist das wirklich wahr, was Du sagst?*" –– just as it probably would also be in english ("*Really?" / "Is that really true, what you're saying?*").

Answer (score 2):

```
Du: »Gerade war auf der Straße wirklich noch nichts los!«
Gesprächspartner: »Wirklich?«
Du: »Wirklich!«
```

alternativ:

```
Du: »Würde ich es sonst sagen?«
```

oder:

```
Du: »Sicher!«
```

Auch möglich sind aber auch, wie gefragt

```
Ja.
Nein.
```

Die Aufgabe einer bekräftigenden Betonung ist es, Zweifel über die Interpretation von ja oder nein zu beseitigen. Wer zweifelt, ob er verstanden wird, weil die Kommunikation schriftlich ist, fährt aber mit `wirklich` nicht schlecht.